Block a Location Change in React
I've just upgraded Router v6.5.0 to 6.26.0.
I have a form and want to intercept any location changes in a web browser if the form has not been saved.
For example, if I'm on page /profile and try to click away to /about, I want to display a custom modal that asks me if I want to save my progress.
After clicking YES or NO, I'd like to proceed to the intended location.

hi oh you want a code snippet i presume? would you mind sharing the form code?

@DerekRoberts The form code is not really needed. Right now I'm looking at useLocation and useHistory but don't know where to look. I don't want to manually have to assign onClick handlers to everything on the screen.

@DerekRoberts Any time the location is about to change I want to intercept that change and cancel it basically and then manually navigate based on custom logic. Doing something like window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload) doesn't do what I want because it only triggers when I do something like a reload.

ok I would suggest history.block with what you currently have in your form.

@DerekRoberts I'm actually using Router v6 and it looks like useNavigate has replaced useHistory

I am making reference to doc it says useNavigate has replaced useHistory

React Router has a useBlocker hook to do just what you want:

The useBlocker hook allows you to prevent the user from navigating away from the current location, and present them with a custom UI to allow them to confirm the navigation.

const Form = () => {
  ...

  const blocker = useBlocker(({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) => (
    currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname
    && /* Other conditions */
  ));

  return (
    ...

    {blocker.state === "blocked" && (
      <div>
        <p>Are you sure you want to leave?</p>

        <button onClick={() => blocker.proceed()}>
          Proceed
        </button>

        <button onClick={() => blocker.reset()}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    )}

    ...
  );
}


I am getting this error useBlocker must be used within a data router My App.jsx has routes between <Routes></Routes> tags

@Dex Ah, well, I guess it means this feature is only available with routers supporting the new data APIs.

As a gotcha, if the blocker triggers and you don't call blocker.reset() then you'll get this error A router only supports one blocker at a time
